# Item list reorder

Tags: channel-entries

Help! I am an administrator and my developer out of the country (12 hour time lag), and I am trying to pitch hit a solution. We are a nonprofit organization that sells courses. Our website has gone live with the new semester's courses, but they are not ordered in a logical sequence on the Registration page. How do I change the item list order? Specific screen is https://www.houstonseminar.org/index.php/registration/

Thank you! Janice

Comment: Which type of sorting you want to do?.. By date,  title,  entry id?  Asc or desc order?

Answer (score 1):

Low Reorder was created for this purpose: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder